# Create a log of lines of code changes per file and commit with git

Tags: git, github

I would like to reflect upon my work on a repository of the past two years, and thus I am trying to compute usage statistics similar to the github.com graphs page, but a little more sophisticated.

Therefore, I am trying to get a list where each row is an event of a file changed with the date and the number of lines changed.

For example, this could be the output:

```
2017-01-12 commit1 README.md +30
2017-01-12 commit1 main.tex +15
2017-03-12 commit2 main.tex +15
2017-05-01 commit3 README.md -10
```

I found a gist that pretty-prints the commits with a date:

```
git log --date=iso --pretty=format:"%h%x09%an%x09%ad%x09%s" > commits.iso.tsv.txt
```

This, however, is too broad. I would like to have an entry *per file and line change*. The idea is to later compute statistics on file extensions (i.e. code files, documentation files, ...).

How could I approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you do something like:

```
git log --stat --oneline
```

And post process it from there? There is also `--numstat` instead of `--stat` which might be more of what you are after.

More details can be found on the [Git](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) website. (if that's not right, look at `--dirstat` ([ref](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#git-log---dirstatltparam1param282308203gt))